# SocketTimeoutException помогите обработать ошибку

Tags: java, jsoup

При выполнении кода:

```
for (int j = a ; j <= b; j++) {
    try {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("какой-то URL" + j).ignoreHttpErrors(true).timeout(1000 * 5).get();
    }
}
```

Иногда выскакивает ошибка `SocketTimeoutException`.

Могу ли я обработать ее таким образом, чтобы цикл продолжил работу с места возникновения ошибки? Верна ли моя реализация?

```
catch (SocketTimeoutException ste) {
    System.out.println("Не удаётся подключиться. Пробуем снова");
    j--;
    continue;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> могу ли я обработать ее таким образом, чтобы цикл продолжил работу с места возникновения ошибки?

Да, можете.

> Верна ли моя реализация?

Да, верна.

Для проверки Вы можете изначально задать маленький тайм-аут.

Например, результат выполнения вот этого кода:

```
for (int j=1; j<=10; j++) {
    try {
        System.out.println("Итерация #" + j);
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.yandex.ru/").timeout(100).get();
        System.out.println(" - Ок");
    } catch (SocketTimeoutException ste) {
        System.out.println(" - Fail");
        j--;
        continue;
    }
}
```

У меня вот такой:

```
Итерация #1
 - Ок
Итерация #2
 - Fail
Итерация #2
 - Ок
Итерация #3
 - Ок
Итерация #4
 - Ок
Итерация #5
 - Fail
Итерация #5
 - Ок
Итерация #6
 - Ок
Итерация #7
 - Ок
Итерация #8
 - Fail
Итерация #8
 - Ок
Итерация #9
 - Ок
Итерация #10
 - Fail
Итерация #10
 - Fail
Итерация #10
 - Ок
```

Разумеется, у Вас он может быть другой.

Comment: Спасибо. Отмечу как правильный после таймаута

Comment: @РоманDriveMind, Для проверки Вы можете заранее задать очень маленький тайм-аут.

Comment: Все сработало. Спасибо